# FindVertexCut & FindEdgeCut

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 12.1**

`FindVertexCut` is new in 9.0.

*Note: Before 10.3, the bug can be reproduced by wrapping the first argument in `Graph`*.

---

Suppose I have this graph, given by:

```
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, 
   R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, 
   R8 -> R6};
```

its directed graph is below. When I use `FindVertexCut[edges,TX,RX]` it returns node `{R5, R6}`. To disconnect this graph I should be getting `{R5,R6,R9}`. Any advice? Second Question: On larger graphs, how can I find the minimum cut sets and minimum path sets where they may contain 1 element, 2 elements, 3 elements, ..., n elements?

[image]

Comment: You can use the `{}` button to display code properly.

Comment: This seems wrong to me.  `FindShortestPath[Graph[edges], TX, RX]` gives `{TX, R7, R9, RX}` which is unaffected by the cuts returned.

Comment: you should contact support@wolfram.com and report it.

Comment: Yet another bug! Is there any bug-free graph related functions? :(

Comment: Still not quite right